# How to Analyze multi-file forms with Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I have a form split in 3 different jpg files, a file for each page, is it possible to instruct Form Recognizer to consider them as a single form?

Should I first merge in a single file? Which is the best free java lib to merge 3 different jpg in a single PDF file?

Thank You

Comment: This is actually a great topic, but what language of code do you want to use to achieve this? Leaving this question as it is is likely to be closed as it is asking for advice on what software to use, perhaps this should be posted on super user?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to merge the 3 jpg files into a single file.
You could try to merge it to a TIFF file, which is supported by Az Form Recognizer, and it supports multiple images/pages.
And this seems to be possible in Java without any additional library.
Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872701/combine-multiple-tif-and-jpeg-into-single-tif-file-has-huge-size) as it may give you an idea.

Moreover, if all documents have the same number of pages and layout, you can use a custom model [trained without labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=preview%2Cv2-1&pivots=programming-language-csharp#train-a-custom-model) to analyze your form.
In case a model without labels doesn't give you good results, try [training it with labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool?tabs=v2-1).